# How to use JSDOM with a external HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, backend, jsdom

i am a new at javascript and web development. I am trying to make a website. But now, i have an another problem.

My code :

```js
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
global.document = new JSDOM(html).window.document;
```

In this code, how can add my index.html file instead of "html" ?